# Semi-transparent mouse cursor on Windows

Tags: libgdx, mouse

I want to change the mouse cursor for a desktop game I am writing with libGDX. That is working well under Linux, however, under Windows semi-transparent cursor pixels are not being rendered at all. That means I am unable to anti-alias the cursor image.

For sure there must be a way to render semi-transparent mouse cursors under Windows, like it's possible under Linux. Any ideas what I could do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not possible to render semi-transparent cursor pixels under Windows. The workaround seems to be to hide the default cursor and render your own... (I am happy for better ideas though.)

Comment: I am pretty sure windows vista allows this as it uses rgba based cursors